# what is the cooresponding return value type for NSRelationshipDescription in NSFetchrRequst.propertiesToFetch?

Tags: core-data

I used an NSFetchReuest to get grouped data count , the attribute to group on is a relationship attribute, which I also want to get in return result. So I set NSFetchReuest's propertiesToFetch , and propertiesToGroupBy. The execution result is an array of dictionaries. But I cannot get the destination object of the relationship. Or how should I get the destination object of the relationship?  Code as below

```
    let entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName( "Record" as NSString, inManagedObjectContext: moc)

    let relationDesc:NSRelationshipDescription = entityDesc?.relationshipsByName["relationName" as NSString] as NSRelationshipDescription;

    let keyPathExpression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "time" as NSString)
    let countExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [keyPathExpression])
    var countExpDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
    countExpDescription.name = "count";
    countExpDescription.expression = countExpression;
    countExpDescription.expressionResultType = NSAttributeType.Integer32AttributeType;


    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Record" as NSString)
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [relationDesc, countExpDescription];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType;
    fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = [relationDesc];


    let results = moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)
```

I set an NSRelationshipDescription in the fetchRequest's proertiesToFetch , the code above can compile and run, but when I try to fetch the results

```
  for eachResult in results!
  {
  let eachResultDict = eachResult as [String:AnyObject];

  let relatedObject = eachResultDict["relationName"] ;
  let count =  eachResultDict["count"] ;
  }
```

I cannot determine what to do with relatedObject, It's not the type of destination data model... When I try to print it, it just return a hex number....  How to get the related object?
The code is a bit long , I hope my title helps make the topic clear~, thanks~

Answer (score 1):

`relationDesc:NSRelationshipDescription` is not a NSExpressionDescription

Try coding a `relationName:NSExpressionDescription` similar to how you coded the `countExpDescription`.